# Caching List of objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance of system.runtime.caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157340/performance-of-system-runtime-caching)

I need to cache list of objects (less than 50 objects with 10-20 fields) which caching method is which caching mehod is better.

`EnterpriseLibrary Caching` or `system.runtime.caching`

Comment: not only performance, which one of these consumes less resources(memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a relatively small amount of objects, I would recommend using `system.runtime.caching` so that you can avoid the overhead of using the EnterpriseLibrary. You could also consider instantiating a [ConcurrenctDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) to store your cached objects - especially if you want to take more control of the lifetime of the objects (expiration policy etc).

If you had been creating a web application I would have recommended that you use `System.Web.Caching.Cache` rather than `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`. We have had issues with `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`, see the following SO article for details:-

- [MemoryCache Empty : Returns null after being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422859/memorycache-disposed-in-web-application)

Comment: not web application, windows form application

Comment: Unfortunately the question is tagged with winforms, not asp.net, making this answer kind of off-topic.

Comment: @Destrictor fair enough, I missed that.